# Reduzindo o tamanho da foto

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Estou gravando as foto tiradas pelo meu aplicativo no banco sqlite, sei que não é muito recomendado mais preciso transferir estas fotos para um banco de dados central que unifica todos os dados de todos aplicativos.

A forma que eu estou reduzindo e gravando no banco sqlite é desta forma:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = (App.bitmap);
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
 bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
 byte[] ba = stream.ToArray();
 string bal = Base64.EncodeToString(ba, Base64.Default);
```

App.bitmap é que recebe a foto tira na hora no método  OnActivityResult . Depois disso gravo no banco passando a variável "bal".

O problema está na hora de buscar esta imagem, no meu select eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Pesquisando na internet esse erro é retornando por causa do tamanho do cursor que têm no máximo 2MB.

Será que estou compactando a imagem de forma errada? Ou será que o jeito que eu estou recebendo a foto no select está errada?

O meu select está da seguinte forma:

```
  private void MostraFoto()
    {
        players = new ArrayList();
        clslogin abrir = new clslogin();

        //ultimoatend();
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), abrir.Nome_banco);
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformAndroid(), path);
        sqldb = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(path, null, DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadwrite);

        sqldb = SQLiteDatabase.OpenOrCreateDatabase(path, null);


        Android.Database.ICursor sqldb_cursor = null;
        sqldb_query = @"select foto,descricao from  foto
        where lugar_id = '"+abrir.Id_lugar+"' and pessoa_id = '"+abrir.Id_pessoa+"'";
        sqldb_cursor = sqldb.RawQuery(sqldb_query, null);

        if (!(sqldb_cursor != null))
        {

        }

        if (sqldb_cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {   
             foto = (sqldb_cursor.GetString(0));
            descricao = (sqldb_cursor.GetString(1));
        }
    }
```

Sem buscar a foto o select não retorna o erro citado acima. Conto a ajuda de vocês.

Comment: Pesquisei um pouco sobre e creio que o seu problema é exatamente esse que você disse: os dados do seu cursor provavelmente excedem 2MB. A forma que busca está certa, caso contrário outro erro deveria ser mostrado.

Comment: @Perozzo Olá como vai, obrigado por responder e desculpa a demora do meu retorno. O problema era exatamente isso eu conseguir resolver diminuído o tamanho da imagem. Eu só ainda não sei como marcar como resolvido aqui no StackOverflow...rsrsrs.  Mais uma vez obrigado pela resposta. Forte Abraço.

Comment: Buenas! Sem problemas. Creio que como você mesmo chegou a uma solução, você pode deletar a pergunta, ou responder a sua própria pergunta colocando a sua solução e aí sim marcar como resposta. Abraço.